# What is the earliest attested mention of the fact that a parallelepiped in Euclidean 3-space can be decomposed into six tetrahedra?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

- The question is in the title.
- A pictorial representation of what this is about is the following:
  [image]

<sub>(created with [GeoGebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoGebra) and [GIMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP))</sub>

- The [orthoschemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%A4fli_orthoscheme) named after [Ludwig Schläfli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Schl%C3%A4fli) are very relevant but more special, and I suspect that the above decomposition has been recognizably described much earlier than the mid 1800s.
- I would also appreciate a view on whether this recognizably occurs in Euclid's elements. To me it seems it doesn't.
- Are there attested extant non-European mentionings of this?